# Resgatar valores dos inputs selecionados no DataTable do primefaces

Tags: java, jsf

[image: datatable]
Tentei usar ajax e a opção `f:attribute`, mas não consigo resgatar os valores necessários, ou seja, a linha selecionada e o valor do `input`. Gostaria de uma ajuda.
Obrigada.

Comment: Poderia incluir o código do botão que realiza ação?

Answer (score 1):

Basta você criar um atributo no seu Bean do tipo:

```
Lista<SeuObjeto> selecionados;
```

Definir no seu dataTable que ele pode ser selecionado, informando o atributo selection, apontando para a propriedade que voce definiu logo acima e o rowKey, segue um exemplo:

```
    <h:form>
     <p:dataTable var="selecionado" value="#{seuBean.suaListaObjetos}" 
      selection="#{seuBean.selecionados}" rowKey="#{selecionado.id}" >

      <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="@form" />
      <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update="@form" />
      <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@form" />
      <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="@form" />
      <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="@form" />
      <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>

      conteudo do dataTable...........

    </p:dataTable>

   </h:form>
```

Lembrando que ele tem que estar dentro de uma tag `<h:form></h:form>`